# 1-level down crawling using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am very new to Python. I am trying to print (and save) all blog posts in a website using scrapy. I want the spider to crawl only in the main content section. This is my code

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from people.items import PeopleCommentItem

class people(CrawlSpider):
name="people"
  allowed_domains=["http://blog.sina.com.cn/"]
  start_urls=["http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_53d7b5ce0100e7y0.html"]
  rules=[Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://blog.sina.com.cn/",)),  callback='parse_item', follow=True),
#restrict the crawling in the articalContent section only
  Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="articalContent   "]//a/@href')))
  ]

  def parse(self,response):
      hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
      print hxs.select('//div[@class="articalContent   "]//a/text()').extract()
```

Nothing is printed after:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_53d7b5ce0100e7y0.html> (referer: None)
ScrapyDeprecationWarning: scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector is deprecated, instantiate scrapy.Selector instead.
  hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function select. Use .xpath() instead.
  titles= hxs.select('//div[@class="articalContent   "]//a/text()').extract()
2015-03-09 15:46:47-0700 [people] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Can somebody advise what is wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some success with this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

class people(CrawlSpider):
  name="people"
  allowed_domains=["http://blog.sina.com.cn/"]
  start_urls=["http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_53d7b5ce0100e7y0.html"]
  rules=(Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://blog.sina.com.cn/",)),  callback='parse_item', follow=True),
#restrict the crawling in the articalContent section only
  Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[contains(@class, "articalContent")]'))),
  )

  def parse(self,response):
      links = Selector(text=response.body).xpath('//div[contains(@class, "articalContent")]//a//text()')
      for link in links:
          print link.extract()
```